# Differences between participle an adjectives from abstract nouns?

Tags: adjectives

I would like to know why adjectives such as "in love"("enamorado") or "in pain"("adolorido") write in that way and what is the name of this kind of words. Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: Those are nouns (**love**, **pain**) which refer to a state of being when used with the preposition **in**.

Comment: That was useful. I appreciate your time, there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In love" is not an adjective. It is a prepositional phrase, just like "in England", or "after lunch".

It is true that it is most often used as a complement, as in "He was in love", and that adjectives can be used in that way, as in "He was happy". But that does not make it an adjective. Nor does the fact that you might use an adjective to translate it in another language.

Comment: There are so many things in English that in Spanish don´t exist. Thank you very much but I think this is a difficult structure of English language that's why I asked this question.